# Momentjs always returning false with isAfter

Tags: momentjs

Momentjs seems to be returning `isAfter` inconsistently but more often returns false when it seems like it should be true:

`moment('2018-09-26T11:09:68').isAfter('2018-09-26T07:09:00')`

This returned false, however, the first date/time **is** after the second.

Comment: This can have nothing possibly to do with Angular, _especiallz_ since you never even mention it in your question. I've edited it out from tags and title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might due to the seconds(68)

> 11:09:68

in the first time stamp

Comment: Noticed an odd pattern of `moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS');` giving me seconds higher than 60... I changed it to `moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:00');` and resolved it (luckily the seconds don't matter for what I need). However, I don't know why ``moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS');` is giving me an invalid format.

Comment: @dcp3450 It's because [`SS` is fractional seconds](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) (parts of second). Seconds are `ss`.